# How call a function in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, callback

I'm having a problem with node JS.

Basically,I Have this function :

```
let getImageName = function(query,callback){
  Images.getImageById(query,function(err,image){
    return image.filename;
  });
}
```

But when i called this,the console.log() print undefined,and I know that the function getImageName is working.

```
app.get('/api/books/:_id', function(req, res){
Book.getBookById(req.params._id, function(err,book){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(getImageName(book.cover));
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to return a value from a callback to an asynchronous function. They don't work that way. You are treating `getImageById()` like it is synchronous but `getImageById()` is asynchronous (which is possible to infer from the way it takes a callback).

```
Images.getImageById(query,function(err,image){
    return image.filename;
  });
```

There are many solutions depending on your use case. The easiest *could* be to move the `console.log()` to inside that callback. (But if you then change the `console.log()` to a `return` statement, you will have the same problem all over again.)

If this is all confusing, there's a short explanation at https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your response,i solve this using callback. `let getImageName = function(query,callback){
 Images.getImageById(query,function(err,image){
   callback(image.filename);
 });
}` and i make the call `getImageName(book.cover,function(response){
   book.cover = response;
   res.json(book);
  });`  This works for me.